# Calculating a 2D joint probability distribution

Tags: matlab, points, plane, probability-density, accumarray

I have many points inside a square. I want to partition the square in many small rectangles and check how many points fall in each rectangle, i.e. I want to compute the joint probability distribution of the points. I am reporting a couple of common sense approaches, using loops and not very efficient:

```
% Data
N = 1e5;    % number of points
xy = rand(N, 2);    % coordinates of points
xy(randi(2*N, 100, 1)) = 0;    % add some points on one side
xy(randi(2*N, 100, 1)) = 1;    % add some points on the other side
xy(randi(N, 100, 1), :) = 0;    % add some points on one corner
xy(randi(N, 100, 1), :) = 1;    % add some points on one corner
inds= unique(randi(N, 100, 1)); xy(inds, :) = repmat([0 1], numel(inds), 1);    % add some points on one corner
inds= unique(randi(N, 100, 1)); xy(inds, :) = repmat([1 0], numel(inds), 1);    % add some points on one corner

% Intervals for rectangles
K1 = ceil(sqrt(N/5));    % number of intervals along x
K2 = K1;    % number of intervals along y
int_x = [0:(1 / K1):1, 1+eps];    % intervals along x
int_y = [0:(1 / K2):1, 1+eps];    % intervals along y

% First approach
tic
count_cells = zeros(K1 + 1, K2 + 1);
for k1 = 1:K1+1
  inds1 = (xy(:, 1) >= int_x(k1)) & (xy(:, 1) < int_x(k1 + 1));
  for k2 = 1:K2+1
    inds2 = (xy(:, 2) >= int_y(k2)) & (xy(:, 2) < int_y(k2 + 1));
    count_cells(k1, k2) = sum(inds1 .* inds2);
  end
end
toc
% Elapsed time is 46.090677 seconds.

% Second approach
tic
count_again = zeros(K1 + 2, K2 + 2);
for k1 = 1:K1+1
  inds1 = (xy(:, 1) >= int_x(k1));
  for k2 = 1:K2+1
    inds2 = (xy(:, 2) >= int_y(k2));
    count_again(k1, k2) = sum(inds1 .* inds2);
  end
end
count_again_fix = diff(diff(count_again')');
toc
% Elapsed time is 22.903767 seconds.

% Check: the two solutions are equivalent
all(count_cells(:) == count_again_fix(:))
```

How can I do it more efficiently in terms of time, memory, and possibly avoiding loops?

**EDIT -->** I have just found this as well, it's the best solution found so far:

```
tic
count_cells_hist = hist3(xy, 'Edges', {int_x int_y});
count_cells_hist(end, :) = []; count_cells_hist(:, end) = [];
toc
all(count_cells(:) == count_cells_hist(:))
% Elapsed time is 0.245298 seconds.
```

but it requires the Statistics Toolbox.

**EDIT --> Testing solution suggested by chappjc**

```
tic
xcomps = single(bsxfun(@ge,xy(:,1),int_x));
ycomps = single(bsxfun(@ge,xy(:,2),int_y));
count_again = xcomps.' * ycomps; %' 143x143 = 143x1e5 * 1e5x143
count_again_fix = diff(diff(count_again')');
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.737546 seconds.
all(count_cells(:) == count_again_fix(:))
```

Comment: Pssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639518/generate-and-plot-the-empirical-joint-pdf-and-cdf-in-matlab/18640944#18640944

Comment: I am also checking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313949/how-to-plot-joint-distribtuion-of-2-random-variable-having-1000-data - I'm not sure if hist3 can be used to obtain the same result.

Comment: @LuisMendo - That's a very thorough answer to the other question and it is rightly linked here. However, the other question was not specific and contained no code, and hence it was closed.  So, I think francesco's question here warrants answers for making a good attempt at solving the problem. Definite +1 to your well conceived solution to the other question. Just my 2 cents.  :)

Comment: @chappjc Yes, since the other question was closed, it makes sense to answer here.

Comment: @francesco If you use `single` instead of `double` in my solution, it runs twice as fast and should not be a problem since the matrix elements are just 0 and 1.

Comment: @Luis, I have tested your solution at the link provided - it does not return the outcome requested, it is very slow and it also takes a lot of memory (!). Perhaps I got it wrong (?)

Comment: @francesco Did it not speed up much with single?  Maybe because I was testing on an old version if MATLAB. BTW, beware of going over 10 edits when question ownership reverts to the community.

Comment: @chappjc: my previous comment was about the solution suggested by Luis at the link provided above. Use of single improves indeed your solution, especially for N>1e5. What does "beware of going over 10 edits when question ownership reverts to the community" mean?

Comment: Since this question is still getting answers, I thought I would post another one using `accumarray`.  This function is designed for this kind of thing and it is _extemely_ fast; all you have to do is bin your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Improving on code in question

Your loops (and the nested dot product) can be eliminated with `bsxfun` and matrix multiplication as follows:

```
xcomps = bsxfun(@ge,xy(:,1),int_x);
ycomps = bsxfun(@ge,xy(:,2),int_y);
count_again = double(xcomps).'*double(ycomps); %' 143x143 = 143x1e5 * 1e5x143
count_again_fix = diff(diff(count_again')');
```

The multiplication step accomplishes the AND and summation done in `sum(inds1 .* inds2)`, but without looping over the density matrix.  **EDIT**: If you use `single` instead of `double`, execution time is nearly halved, but be sure to convert your answer to `double` or whatever is required for the rest of the code.  On my computer this takes around **0.5 sec**.

Note: With `rot90(count_again/size(xy,1),2)` you have a CDF, and in `rot90(count_again_fix/size(xy,1),2)` you have a PDF.

### Using accumarray

Another approach is to use `accumarray` to make the joint histogram after we bin the data.

Starting with `int_x`, `int_y`, `K1`, `xy`, etc.:

```
% take (0,1) data onto [1 K1], following A.Dondas approach for easy comparison
ii = floor(xy(:,1)*(K1-eps))+1; ii(ii<1) = 1; ii(ii>K1) = K1;
jj = floor(xy(:,2)*(K1-eps))+1; jj(jj<1) = 1; jj(jj>K1) = K1;

% create the histogram and normalize
H = accumarray([ii jj],ones(1,size(ii,1)));
PDF = H / size(xy,1); % for probabilities summing to 1
```

On my computer, this takes around **0.01 sec**.

The output is the same as A.Donda's converted from sparse to full (`full(H)`). Although, as he A.Donda pointed out, it is correct to have the dimensions be `K1`x`K1`, rather than the size of `count_again_fix` in the OPs code that was `K1+1`x`K1+1`.

To get the CDF, I believe you can simply apply `cumsum` to each axis of the PDF.

Comment: +It works! Thanks! I am trying to do that with hist3.

Comment: Note to all: I'm not necessarily going for a solution to the general joint probability distribution question, but rather for a way to change francesco's code to "do it more efficiently in terms of time, memory, and possibly avoiding loops".  There's a fine line here I think, and it comes down to the scope and quality of the two questions. I'm going outside now. :p

Comment: Using hist3 seems to be the best option if the Statistics Toolbox is available - otherwise the solution suggested by chappjc is the best alternative solution that I have tested so far.

Comment: Your solution using accumarray is very fast indeed - it is comparable with my mex function! Although I need also the extremes, 0s and 1s, so I think the size of the matrix should be (K1+1)x(K2+1) - consider that I am using the *edges*, not the *bins*.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a simple mex function which works very well when N is large. Of course it's cheating but still ...

The function is

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    unsigned long int hh, ctrl;       /*  counters                       */
    unsigned long int N, m, n;        /*  size of matrices               */
    unsigned long int *xy;            /*  data                           */
    unsigned long int *count_cells;   /*  joint frequencies              */
    /*  matrices needed */
    mxArray *count_cellsArray;

/*  Now we need to get the data */
    if (nrhs == 3) {
        xy = (unsigned long int*) mxGetData(prhs[0]);
        N = (unsigned long int) mxGetM(prhs[0]);
        m = (unsigned long int) mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
        n = (unsigned long int) mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);
    }

/*  Then build the matrices for the output */
    count_cellsArray = mxCreateNumericMatrix(m + 1, n + 1, mxUINT32_CLASS, mxREAL);
    count_cells = mxGetData(count_cellsArray);
    plhs[0] = count_cellsArray;

    hh = 0; /* counter for elements of xy */
    /* for all points from 1 to N */
    for(hh=0; hh<N; hh++) {
        ctrl = (m + 1) * xy[N + hh] + xy[hh];
        count_cells[ctrl] = count_cells[ctrl] + 1;
    }
}
```

It can be saved in a file "joint_dist_points_2D.c", then compiled:

```
mex joint_dist_points_2D.c
```

And check it out:

```
% Data
N = 1e7;    % number of points
xy = rand(N, 2);    % coordinates of points
xy(randi(2*N, 1000, 1)) = 0;    % add some points on one side
xy(randi(2*N, 1000, 1)) = 1;    % add some points on the other side
xy(randi(N, 1000, 1), :) = 0;    % add some points on one corner
xy(randi(N, 1000, 1), :) = 1;    % add some points on one corner
inds= unique(randi(N, 1000, 1)); xy(inds, :) = repmat([0 1], numel(inds), 1);    % add some points on one corner
inds= unique(randi(N, 1000, 1)); xy(inds, :) = repmat([1 0], numel(inds), 1);    % add some points on one corner

% Intervals for rectangles
K1 = ceil(sqrt(N/5));    % number of intervals along x
K2 = ceil(sqrt(N/7));    % number of intervals along y
int_x = [0:(1 / K1):1, 1+eps];    % intervals along x
int_y = [0:(1 / K2):1, 1+eps];    % intervals along y

% Use Statistics Toolbox: hist3
tic
count_cells_hist = hist3(xy, 'Edges', {int_x int_y});
count_cells_hist(end, :) = []; count_cells_hist(:, end) = [];
toc
% Elapsed time is 4.414768 seconds.

% Use mex function
tic
xy2 = uint32(floor(xy ./ repmat([1 / K1, 1 / K2], N, 1)));
count_cells = joint_dist_points_2D(xy2, uint32(K1), uint32(K2));
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.586855 seconds.

% Check: the two solutions are equivalent
all(count_cells_hist(:) == count_cells(:))
```

Comment: Good contribution!  But MEX is kind of a cheat, yeah.  ;)  However, I used a MEX file when making joint PDFs for my research, so at the end of the day I would agree that is the way to go. However, for this `N=1e7` test data, my updated `accumarray` approach takes 1.1 seconds on my PC, so that might be a good general alternative, no toolboxes required.

Comment: I Agree! I tested your solution with accumarray and it is fast even with N=3e7! Chapeau!

Answer (score 0):

chappjc's answer and using `hist3` are all good, but since I happened to want to have something like this some time ago and for some reason didn't find `hist3` I wrote it myself, and I thought I'd post it here as a bonus. It uses `sparse` to do the actual counting and returns the result as a sparse matrix, so it may be useful for dealing with a multimodal distribution where different modes are far apart – or for someone who doesn't have the Statistics Toolbox.

Application to francesco's data:

```
K1 = ceil(sqrt(N/5));
[H, xs, ys] = hist2d(xy(:, 1), xy(:, 2), [K1 K1], [0, 1 + eps, 0, 1 + eps]);
```

Called with output parameters the function just returns the result, without it makes a color plot.

Here's the function:

function [H, xs, ys] = hist2d(x, y, n, ax)

```
% plot 2d-histogram as an image
%
% hist2d(x, y, n, ax)
% [H, xs, ys] = hist2d(x, y, n, ax)
%
% x:    data for horizontal axis
% y:    data for vertical axis
% n:    how many bins to use for each axis, default is [100 100]
% ax:   axis limits for the plot, default is [min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)]
% H:    2d-histogram as a sparse matrix, indices 1 & 2 correspond to x & y
% xs:   corresponding vector of x-values
% ys:   corresponding vector of y-values
%
% x and y have to be column vectors of the same size. Data points
% outside of the axis limits are allocated to the first or last bin,
% respectively. If output arguments are given, no plot is generated;
% it can be reproduced by "imagesc(ys, xs, H'); axis xy".


% defaults
if nargin < 3
    n = [100 100];
end
if nargin < 4
    ax = [min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)];
end

% parameters
nx = n(1);
ny = n(2);
xl = ax(1 : 2);
yl = ax(3 : 4);

% generate histogram
i = floor((x - xl(1)) / diff(xl) * nx) + 1;
i(i < 1) = 1;
i(i > nx) = nx;
j = floor((y - yl(1)) / diff(yl) * ny) + 1;
j(j < 1) = 1;
j(j > ny) = ny;
H = sparse(i, j, ones(size(i)), nx, ny);

% generate axes
xs = (0.5 : nx) / nx * diff(xl) + xl(1);
ys = (0.5 : ny) / ny * diff(yl) + yl(1);

% possibly plot
if nargout == 0
    imagesc(ys, xs, H')
    axis xy
    clear H xs ys
end
```

Comment: The function is brilliant but the outcome is not exactly the same - I guess the edges on the right are treated differently. I'm trying to understand if I can fix it accordingly.

Comment: Thx! Maybe its because "indices 1 & 2 correspond to y & x"? I did it that way because that's the way imagesc wants it input, but maybe that was a bad idea. In that case, transposition should fix it.

Comment: Also, your hist3 solution produces a 143 x 143 matrix, while K1 = K2 = 142, and my function produces a 142 x 142 accordingly.

Comment: @francesco, I changed my function to give the output with the "natural" order of coordinates. The remaining difference is due to the fact that `hist3` with specifying 'Edges' ignores data points lying outside, while my function counts them towards the margin bins. Its output is identical to that of `hist3` if called like this: `hist3(xy, 'Ctrs', {xs ys})` where `xs` and `ys` are the bin centers returned by my function. Thanks for pointing out these inconsistencies!

Comment: @A.Donda That's a nice way. Instead of using `sparse` to do counting, MATLAB's `accumarray` is quite nice for accumulating binned data like this.  I posted a second solution in my answer just for completeness.