# two dimensional histogram of an image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, histogram

I have an image. i am calculating I,u,v  components for it.

`I = (R+G+B)/3`

`u = R-G`

`v=  G-B;`

Now , I want to find two-dimensional histograms
over the chromatic information (u; v).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? If I Google the title of your question there are quite a few promising looking results that I would try in the same situation. Have you done that?

Comment: basically they are passing only one paramater in hist and the other parameter is the size of the bin, whereas I want to pass two parameter when creating histogram

Comment: basically they are passing only one paramater in hist and the other parameter is the size of the bin, whereas I want to pass two parameter when creating histogram i.e u and v. I want to know the co occurence of (u,v) pair. secondly i have modified the code given in the link for I, u,v space but that's not giving the right solution. http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/264526

Comment: In that case you should add your modified code to the question. It would also be great if you added some example input data to work with too (you can just type in some values representing a tiny image). Say what result you expect and what you are getting instead, (or where the script is crashing and what error message you are getting). That way people trying to answer your question can see what the problem is.

Comment: Look into `hist3` if you have the right toolbox.

Comment: This answer may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639518/generate-and-plot-the-empirical-joint-pdf-and-cdf-in-matlab

Comment: 2d-histograms are also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19745917/2056067

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sparse` to creatre a sparse 2D matrix that counts the `u`-`v` entries.
Note that you'll have to adjust the indices in the `u`-`v` dimension to be in range `1...|u|` and `1...|v|` (and not negative or fractional).

```
[uu ui] = unique( round(u(:)) ); % adjust u index using unique command
[vv vi] = unique( round(v(:)) );
twoDhist = sparse( ui, vi, 1, numel(uu), numel(vv) );
twoDhist = spfun( @(x) x/numel(ui), twoDhist ); % normalize hist to sum to 1

figure;
imagesc( vv, uu, twoDhist ); colormap jet; colorbar; axis image
```